# DRY controllers for nested routes in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dry

I have a project that's set up with the following models. Each `->` represents a `has_many` relation:

```
Users->Goals->Milestones
```

My routes for the `Milestones` look like this:

```
  user_goal_milestones GET    /users/:user_id/goals/:goal_id/milestones(.:format)          milestones#index
                         POST   /users/:user_id/goals/:goal_id/milestones(.:format)          milestones#create
 new_user_goal_milestone GET    /users/:user_id/goals/:goal_id/milestones/new(.:format)      milestones#new
edit_user_goal_milestone GET    /users/:user_id/goals/:goal_id/milestones/:id/edit(.:format) milestones#edit
     user_goal_milestone GET    /users/:user_id/goals/:goal_id/milestones/:id(.:format)      milestones#show
                         PUT    /users/:user_id/goals/:goal_id/milestones/:id(.:format)      milestones#update
                         DELETE /users/:user_id/goals/:goal_id/milestones/:id(.:format)      milestones#destroy
```

I find myself in many of the "functions" in the Milestones controller doing a lot of this:

```
def index do
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @goal = Goal.find(params[:goal_id])
end

def edit do
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @goal = Goal.find(params[:goal_id])
end
```

How can I modify my controller so I don't have to define `@user` and `@goal` all the time? 
I tried putting them directly at the top, right after the start of the class definition block, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the params are always the same you can create a method like this

```
def set_user_and_goal
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @goal = Goal.find(params[:goal_id])

end
```

and put it in a before_filter at the top

```
before_filter :set_user_and_goal
```

and set it to whatever action you like

```
before_filter :set_user_and_goal, :only => [:edit, :index]
```

Edit:

Also, to make sure that it doesn't blow up in your face, you can do

```
@user = params.has_key?(:user_id) ? User.find(params[:user_id]) : nil
```

and as requested.. make sure that the goal belongs to the user by doing something like

```
@goals = @user.goals.find(params[:goal_id])
```

Comment: just make sure that you always have a :user_id and a :goal_id

Comment: This can cause unexpected behavior in the application. You should test if the passed goal really belongs to the passed user, or else things can get ugly. Please add the tests in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

you an always define your own helper methods

```
def goal_milestone(goal)
  user_goal_milestone(goal.user, goal)
end
```

You can add it to your application_helper, and then use any in any of your views. This would create the small helper methods as you asked in your question.

looking for a gem that does this for you didn't show me anything, but you can code this yourself in a generic way.

Comment: Where would I put this helper? And how would I use it?

Comment: Updated my answer, you might want to check